# How would one set a public variable in a monobehavior script from a general script in C# Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a difficult time setting the public playerChoice int from the monobehavior script "PlayerController" in this general script for tracking attacks in this RPG game I am working on.

```
public void CalculatePlayerChoice(int playerChoice) //Takes input and sets the playerChoice int accordingly
    {
        Debug.Log("CalculatePlayerChoice is being ran");
        if(Input.GetKey(attackKey)) { //if the attackKey is pressed
            playerController.setPlayerChoice(playerChoiceNum); //set playerChoice to playerChoiceNUm
        }
        else {
            playerController.setPlayerChoice(playerChoice);
        }
    }
```

I have created an object for PlayerController.cs called "playerController."

```
public PlayerController playerController;
```

I have also created and used a setPlayerChoice method in PlayerController.cs. Hopefully this is enough information to diagnose the problem. I have spent 2 days now trying to fix this bug. Bedankt!

I have tried making the general script a monobehavior as well, to declare the PlayerController.cs object, in order to connect the two scripts on the player character, and set the variable directly, but I am unable to create a constructor in doing that.

I have also attempted creating a new monobehavior script entirely for executing methods using the variables saved to the general script, but that required that I set the object for the general class in the second monobehavior, which doesn't work.

Comment: You have to pass the reference of PlayerController through the func's parameters.
Also MonoBehaviours are not created the usual C# way, through new.

You AddComponent<T> to an existing GameObject, just like to access one such instance, you do gameObject.GetComponent<T>.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if we are talking about `MonoBehaviours` (about `Components`, actually, because `Component` is a base class of anything that can be attached to `GameObject` in Unity3d), do not think about them as "normal" c# classes.

They have [their own lifecycle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), and they do not use a constructor (at least without some magic and constraints, but it is not the cool way to use it, IMO).

So, if you need to provide a link from one `MonoBehaviour` to another, you have several options:

- The most Unity-way-like is to mark needed field in your MonoBehaviour as `[SerializedField]`. This will lead this field to be seen in the Unity Editor Inspector window and can be set there. More info can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).
- The second option to pass anything to your MonoBehaviour is the same as in the "usual" c# - if you have a link to the concrete instance of MonoBehaviour, you have access to any of its public fields and methods to pass anything you want to it. You can get a link to the instance in case you add MonoBehaviour yourself `AddComponent<T>()` method[(link)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) returns a link to the created instance) or by calling `GetComponent<T>()` on the `GameObject` instance, which your MonoBehaviour is attached to (for example, if you are instantiating your `GameObject`, you can use `GetComponent<T>[3]` ([link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)) on it to get the link to the attached instance of `T`).

Comment: It's worth saying that [`TryGetComponent<T>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html) is a better alternative to `GetComponent<T>()`, because it's safer and it doesn't allocate garbage when the component doesn't exist. Moreover, `GetComponent<T>()` and ``TryGetComponent<T>()`` can be inefficient if you use it a lot, therefore their use should be minimized.

Comment: Sorry, I think there is some confusion. I am not trying to bring an integer from one monobehavior to another, I am trying to set an integer in a monobehavior from a general object class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had organized it into two seperate scripts, when I should have just placed the general object class under the monobhevior and called it that way. Dank je voor uw steun!